# MongoDB $currentDate operator

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm using MongoDB $currentDate operator to update some dates that are in the past to today. My query:

```
db.my_collection.updateMany({ _id: {$in: ["123", "345"]} }, {$currentDate: {reportingDate: true}})
```

This results in the field getting updated to current date and time. Example:

```
2023-05-26T14:10:30
```

But, I would like only the date to be current, with time all zeros, like:

```
2023-05-26T00:00:00
```

Can I have this be done with $currentDate somehow?

Answer (score 2):

As suggested per [official doc](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/reference/operator/update/currentDate/#aggregation-alternative-to--currentdate), one of the alternatives you can use is chaining up `$dateTrunc` with `$$NOW` variable in update with aggregation pipeline.

```js
db.collection.update({
  _id: {
    $in: [
      "123",
      "345"
    ]
  }
},
[
  {
    $set: {
      reportingDate: {
        $dateTrunc: {
          date: "$$NOW",
          unit: "day"
        }
      }
    }
  }
],
{
  multi: true
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/25c7rryYgAn)